# WooCommerce: update custom fields after checkout validation failure

Tags: php, custom-field, ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

In my project I'm customizing some of the WooCommerce features.
My "shipping methods" are:
1. delivery
2. take away

I also added a custom field in the checkout page that is a `<select>` populated with the valid times for delivery (case "1") or for the take away (case "2").

It may happen that a user selects `2. take away` in the cart page, then selects a time valid for "2", but then changes to `1. delivery` and the selected time may not be valid anymore, neither the option list and the custom field label.

Of course i'm using the `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook to warn the user via `wc_add_notice()`, but even if the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook is triggered (that's where i create the select list), the `<select>` values are not updated.

I think there is an AJAX call that is related only to the shipping method and doesn't update the other checkout fields, although `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook is triggered.

How to update the custom fields?
Do i need some js/jquery/AJAX?

Or: can a custom field be related to a shipping method (and get updated via AJAX with it)? How?

**EDIT**

Custom field code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'fty_filter_checkout_fields' );
function my_filter_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $must_deliver   =   WC()->cart->shipping_total > 0.0;   // true=deliver, false=take away

    // some complex code to calculate time lists omitted, samples array instead:

    $delivery_time_list =   array(
        "deliver 10:00",
        "deliver 11:00",
        "deliver 12:00",
        "deliver 13:00"
    );

    $takeaway_time_list =   array(
        "takeaway 10:00",
        "takeaway 10:30",
        "takeaway 11:00",
        "takeaway 11:30",
        "takeaway 12:00",
        "takeaway 12:30",
        "takeaway 13:00",
        "takeaway 13:30"
    );

    // add the new conditional field
    if($must_deliver) {
        $fields['my_delivery_datetime'] = array(
            'my_delivery_time' => array(
                'type'      => 'select',
                'options'   => $delivery_time_list,
                'required'  => true,
                'label'     => __('Delivery time')
            )
        );
    } else {
        $fields['my_delivery_time'] = array(
            'my_delivery_time' => array(
                'type'      => 'select',
                'options'   => $takeaway_time_list,
                'required'  => true,
                'label'     => __('Take away time')
            )
        );
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

an idea of the validation code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_checkout_date_time_validation', 30, 1);
function my_checkout_date_time_validation($doh) {
    $time = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'my_delivery_time');
    $shipping = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'shipping_method', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

    if(strpos($time, "deliver")!==FALSE && strpos($shipping[0], "local_pickup")!==FALSE) {
        wc_add_notice('Please re-select take away time', 'error');
    } else if(strpos($time, "takeaway")!==FALSE && strpos($shipping[0], "distance_based_rate")!==FALSE) {
        wc_add_notice('Please re-select delivery time', 'error');
    }

}
```

here's about shipping methods;

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate', 'add_distance_based_delivery_rate', 10, 2 );
function add_distance_based_delivery_rate( $method, $rate ) {
    $new_rate          = $rate;
    $new_rate['id']    .= ':' . 'distance_based_rate';
    $new_rate['label'] = 'delivery'; // Rename to 'Rushed Shipping'.

    // incredibly complex code used to calculate delivery costs omitted
    $dist_cost  =   1000;

    $new_rate['cost']  += $dist_cost;
    $method->add_rate( $new_rate );
}
```

Thanx!